# Peewee and Flask : 'Database' object has no attribute 'commit_select'

Tags: python, flask, peewee

I'm trying to use Peewee with Flask, but I don't understand why my database connection does not work.

config.py

```
class Configuration(object):
DATABASE = {
    'name': 'test',
    'engine': 'peewee.MySQLDatabase',
    'user': 'root',
    'passwd': 'root'
}
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'shhhh'
```

app/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_peewee.db import Database
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config.Configuration') 
db = Database(app)
import views,models
```

app/models.py

```
from peewee import *
from . import db
database = db

class UnknownField(object):
    def __init__(self, *_, **__): pass
class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database

class Tbcategory(BaseModel):
    insert_dt = DateTimeField()
    name = CharField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tbcategory'
```

I generated models.py with pwiz.

If I try to use it on the interactive console I get the error on the title. If I change the line on models.py from database=db to the original one created by pwiz:

```
db = MySQLDatabase('test', **{'host': '127.0.0.1', 'password': 'root', 'user': 'root'})
```

everything works fine. I can't find for the life of me an example on internet. Either the configuration is all in the app or it's outside in a config.py file but with sqlite or some orther slightly different usages.
Should I stop using Database() from flask_peewee and using the MySQLDatabase directly? How do i use an external file with the configuration?
Note that I use 127.0.0.1 on one method, and no host specification on the other. I did copy from peewee-flask's website.

Comment: Sounds like your config isn't being handled correctly. I think I've found the culprit -> `app.config.from_object('config.Configuration')`. I think you meant to pass that method a config object instead of a string.

Comment: @WyattIsrael thanks, but I did check it twice and it's correct. I have to pass a string. I even tried to make a typo to see if it's loaded. It is indeed loaded when I use the string. I am not sure what happens though.

Comment: Wrong @WyattIsrael -- see my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `Database` wrapper object. To get at the actual Peewee database object, use:

```
app.config.from_object('config.Configuration') 
db = Database(app)
database = db.database  # database is the actual peewee database obj.
```

In your models code:

```
from peewee import *
from . import database  # Import the actual peewee database
```

Comment: It works! Thanks for the help and thanks for peewee.